# AssetManager null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a null pointer exception on the line marked with /*Here*/ in my code. I've spent about 2 hours looking up the AssetManager and how to use it, etc, but still can't figure out why it's null. I've called getAssets() by itself, from the context and from the resources but still I'm getting null. Can anyone help me out here? 
Thanks.

```
package com.hamc17.CatFacts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;

public class FactsActivity extends Activity{

Context context;
Resources res;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceBundle){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceBundle);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    res = context.getResources();

    Button getFactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getFactButton);
    getFactButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast toastMessageOnClick = new Toast(FactsActivity.this);
            toastMessageOnClick.setText(getFact());
            if((toastMessageOnClick.toString()).length()>50)
            {
                toastMessageOnClick.setDuration(10);
            }
            else
            {
                toastMessageOnClick.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
            toastMessageOnClick.show();
        }
    });
}


    String[] factArray = getFactsFromTextFile().split(";");
    private String getFactsFromTextFile(){
/*Here*/ AssetManager assMan = context.getAssets();
        try{
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assMan.open("facts.txt")));
            String line;
            StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
            while((line = buff.readLine()) != null)
            {
                build.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.seperator"));
            }
            return build.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast toastMessage = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toastMessage.setText(e.toString() + "\n Whoops, there was an error! ");
            toastMessage.show();
            return "";
        }
        finally
        {
            try{
                assMan.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Whatever Trevor
            }
        }
    }

private String getFact(){

    String randomFactString = "";
    int factCount = factArray.length;

    Random rng = new Random();
    int randomNum = rng.nextInt()*factCount;

    randomFactString = factArray[randomNum];

    return randomFactString;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing  `setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceBundle){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    Button getFactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getFactButton);
```

`findViewById` looks for a resource with the id in the current inflated layout. So you should set the content of your layout to the activity before initializing views

Also you can use

```
res = getResources();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a local variable to get the Context of the Activity just use getBaseContext(); each time you want to get the reference to the Context.

So something like this instead:

`AssetManager assMan = getBaseContext().getAssets();`

Comment: And @Raghunandan is right, you need to set the View for your Activity

Comment: I have found that depending on the lifecycle and screen rotations calling this each time will get you a reference.

Comment: Did you really call this variable "assMan"? :lol:

Comment: @TjerkW it appears that I did....